# Unable to loop the function to generate a secret code for 1000 times

Tags: python

I have a function to generate out a four letter secret code.

However, I am unable to loop the function to generate a secret code for 1000 times. It prints the code 2 times, and then gets an error stating that list index is out of range.

```
import random

base1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
base2 = ["E", "F", "G", "H"]


def chooseOneLetter(base1, base2):
    ratio = 10
    seed = int(random.uniform (0, ratio*len(base1)+len(base2)))
    if seed < ratio*len(base1):
        chosenLetter = base1[int(seed/ratio)]
        base1.remove(chosenLetter)
    else:
        chosenLetter = base2[(seed - ratio*len(base1))]
        base2.remove(chosenLetter)
    return chosenLetter

def getSecretCode(base1, base2):
    secretCode = ""
    for i in range(4):
        chosenLetter = chooseOneLetter (base1, base2)
        secretCode += chosenLetter
    return secretCode



def Code():
    d = {}
    base1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    base2 = ["E", "F", "G", "H"]
    for i in range(1000):
        secretCode = getSecretCode(base1, base2)
        print(secretCode)


Code()
```

Output:

```
DHCA
BGFE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
    Code()
  File "main.py", line 32, in Code
    secretCode = getSecretCode(base1, base2)
  File "main.py", line 21, in getSecretCode
    chosenLetter = chooseOneLetter (base1, base2)
  File "main.py", line 14, in chooseOneLetter
    chosenLetter = base2[(seed - ratio*len(base1))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are removing letters from the list without replacing them. The length of base1 and base2 become 0, so it throws the index error. Just move the for loop above the list assignments.

```
def Code():
    d = {}
    for i in range(1000):
        base1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
        base2 = ["E", "F", "G", "H"]
        secretCode = getSecretCode(base1, base2)
        print(secretCode)
```